# Are there any application in the exp of log of DFT matrix?

Tags: group-theory, signal-processing

Just a fun thought.

Since the N point DFT matrix $W$ is a complex rotation matrix:

$$W^*W = I$$
$$det(W)=1$$

It may make sense to work on a rotated domain with a projection matrix $W_\phi$:
$$W_\phi=exp(\phi*log(W))$$
which
$$W_0 = I$$
$$W_1 = W$$

After some test on matlab:
$$W_3 = W^*$$
$$W_4 = I$$
$$W_{4-x} = W^{-1}_x ,\space for\space x\in\mathbb{R}$$

Which means it forms a complex Lie group.

If we consider $I$ as a projection to time domain itself, $W_\phi$ is a projection onto a interpolated domain between time & freq domain.

Are there any known application of $W_\phi$?